# How to deal with noisy label for regression model

Tags: python, deep-learning, regression, filtering

Here, I want to filter noisy labels during training and delete noisy labels from the dataset, then retrain clean data. I did it, but I'm not sure if it's correct or not. because the X_train shape before filtering then X_train_clean will be same.

below is X_train, y_train, X_test and y_test shape

[image]

below is the train process and filtering process
[image]

if we look at filtering process the X_train_clean will sama shape as X_train it look like not working.

below is my code:

```
columns = ['Fx']
wavelet = 'db4'
max_iter = 50
iter = 0

# Training Process
Insole = pd.read_csv('0310AyuStand5Min1.txt', header=None, low_memory=False)
SIData =  np.asarray(Insole)

df = pd.read_csv('0310AyuStand5Min1.csv', low_memory=False)
selected_df = df[columns]
FPDatas = selected_df[:]

SmartInsole = np.array(SIData[:]).astype('float32')
FPData = np.array(FPDatas).astype('float32')

for i in range(len(SmartInsole)):
    SmartInsole[i][0] = SmartInsole[i][0] + (iter % max_iter) + 1
    iter += 1

# Scale the smart insole data
minInsole = SmartInsole.min()
maxInsole = SmartInsole.max()
smart_insole_data_scaled = (SmartInsole - minInsole) / (maxInsole - minInsole)

# Scale the force plate data
minForcePlate = FPData.min()
maxForcePlate = FPData.max()
force_plate_data_scaled = (FPData - minForcePlate) / (maxForcePlate - minForcePlate)

#Spliting Data
sample_size = smart_insole_data_scaled.shape[0] # number of samples in train set
time_steps  = smart_insole_data_scaled.shape[1] # number of features in train set
input_dimension = 1               # each feature is represented by 1 number

train_data_reshaped = smart_insole_data_scaled.reshape(sample_size,time_steps,input_dimension)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_data_reshaped[:13000], 
                                                    force_plate_data_scaled[:13000], 
                                                    test_size=0.20, random_state=2)
print(X_train.shape,X_test.shape)
print(y_train.shape,y_test.shape)

"Configurations for ResNet in Regression Mode"
length = X_train.shape[1]   # Number of Features (or length of the signal)
model_width = 64           # Number of Filter or Kernel in the Input Layer
num_channel = 1             # Number of Input Channels
problem_type = 'Regression' # Regression or Classification
output_number = 1           # Number of Outputs in the Regression Mode

Regression_Model = ResNet(length, num_channel, model_width, problem_type=problem_type, 
                          output_nums=output_number).ResNet18()
Regression_Model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), metrics= ['mse']) # Compile Model

Regression_Model.summary()

# Define the fixed loss threshold for noisy instances
loss_threshold = 0.05

# Training loop
num_epochs = 500
batch_size = 64
noisy_indices = []  # Store the indices of noisy instances

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}")
    
    # Train the model
    history = Regression_Model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
    
    # Make predictions on the training set
    y_pred_train = Regression_Model.predict(X_train)
    train_loss = mean_squared_error(y_train, y_pred_train)
    print(train_loss)
    print(loss_threshold)
    
    # Find instances with loss above the threshold
    noisy_indices_epoch = np.where(train_loss > loss_threshold)[0]
    noisy_indices.extend(noisy_indices_epoch)
    noisy_indices = list(set(noisy_indices))  # Remove duplicate indices
    
    # Exclude noisy instances from training data
    X_train_filtered = np.delete(X_train, noisy_indices, axis=0)
    y_train_filtered = np.delete(y_train, noisy_indices, axis=0)
    print(X_train_filtered.shape)
    
    # Early stopping if all instances are noisy
    if len(X_train_filtered) == 0:
        print("All instances are noisy. Stopping training.")
        break
    
    # Retrain the model on filtered data
    Regression_Model.fit(X_train_filtered, y_train_filtered, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, shuffle=True)

# Evaluate the model on test data
loss, mse = Regression_Model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
y_pred_test = Regression_Model.predict(X_test)
```

simple Case is such below

```
X_train                y_train
11, 12, 13, 15  ====>  22.99 clean
11, 12, 13, 15  ====>  22.67 clean
11, 12, 13, 15  ====>  30.67 noisy (need to remove from dataset or relabel it)
```

Please help me check my process to see if that is correct or not, and if not, what should I do? I work based on this algorithm.

[image]

full paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=10113715